# Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I'm using windows server 2008 R2. One day my server got issue with Group Policy. Here is the log in event log:

> The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the
>   computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
>   a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller.  b)
>   Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another
>   domain controller has not replicated to the current domain
>   controller).

I couldn't access Active Directory Users and Control and other things related to Domain.

[image]

[image]

[image: DNS]

Can you tell me how to fix this kind of error? Thanks!

UPDATE: I figured it out. It was the old ip set in host file with server name.

Comment: Tell us about how your DNS client settings are configured. Tell us about your DNS server (is it running on this Domain Controller computer, what Forward Lookup Zones do have configured).

Comment: Is this computer configured to use itself as its DNS server?

Comment: I create a cname and pointed it to this server.

Comment: `I create a cname and pointed it to this server` - What does that mean, exactly?